# Как сделать подобный таб бар?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Как сделать подобный таб-бар как на картинке ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы имеете в виду нижнюю панель? Если да - то как и любой другой элемент разметки. Уточните что именно у вас вызывает затруднения.

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый отклик! Да, имею ввиду нижнюю панель.. т.е. это просто кнопки на черном фоне ?

Comment: Да, подробнее - в ответе.

Comment: Таббар в нижней части экрана - одна из грубейших ошибок в построении интерфейса Android-приложения. Не рекомендую так делать. Подробнее здесь: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Comment: @saturov, спасибо за ответ! В будущем учту) Сейчас так требует ТЗ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для создания подобного вам надо:

1. **LinearLayout** горизонтальный
2. а в нём ещё 4 их же, но вертикальных, с **weight=1**
3. в коих **ImageView** & **TextView**
4. Поместить полученный элемент вниз экрана каким либо из многочисленных способов.

Comment: А ImageView зачем?

Comment: Можно и без неё, используя drawableTop, но мне этот способ не нравится из-за меньшего контроля за размерами изображения.

Comment: По идеи обычной кнопки должно хватить ? А у кнопки будет картинка с иконкой и текстом.. И каким лучше способом прижать все к низу ?

Comment: На счёт кнопок не скажу - ни разу они мне не пригодились. Прижать к низу можно, например, поместив этот элемент в FrameLayout c gravity="bottom". Или в RelativeLayout Указав располагаться ниже вышележащего элемента.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, а как по Вашему лучше прижать к низу?) Экран у меня состоит из: ImageView(логотип), FrameLayout(куда буду грузить фрагменты по нажатию на нижнии кнопки), и ниже кнопки меню..

Comment: Попробуйте RelativeLayout. Либо, раз вы будете фрагменты так переключать, попроуйте табы (см. ответ @andreich). Но там сложнее из-за большого кол-ва нюансов.

Answer (score 2):

Советую воспользоваться TabLayout из саппорт билиотеки. Как им пользоваться, расскажут тут https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout.

Вам лишь стоит поменять немного разметку так, чтобы он был внизу экрана, а не снизу

Comment: Этот ответ должен быть выбран как лучший. Разве что с той поправкой, что табы внизу делать нельзя: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/pure-android.html

Answer (score 0):

Если используешь actionbar то есть официальная  документация 
[Раздел Using split action bar](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

В новом Tabbar тоже можно все это провернуть.

Ну и всегда можно корневой элемент RelativeLayout а в нем уже `layout` с `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` и разметкой табов.

Или так еще
http://envyandroid.com/align-tabhost-at-bottom/